# Paid software for full research paper, journal article viewing

Tags: ebooks, books, journal

I need a paid desktop software which can be used to view full research papers, journal articles. There was a software (I don't remember the name) that can be purchased, and that software gives free access to thousands of paid articles. Need that kind of software. I had access to my university online library, but now I don't have access. So, looking for this kind of software. Any recommendations?

Comment: Maybe you remember scopus (https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus), which itself is an abstract and citation database, but allows librarians to link to the full texts of articles as far as they have subscribed to the respective journals? So you would still have to subscribe to the journals themselves, too

Comment: Many pre-print copies of papers are uploaded by authors to http://www.researchgate.net/

Comment: @Pretty_Girl: If an answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 1):

If gratis is OK, you can do the following:

1. Install a torrent client
2. See [Bulk download Sci-Hub papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7084/1652)

You can still donate to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/features/) which is available for Desktop, Mobile and On-line research & collaboration.

Comment: It's for citation management I guess, not to view full paid research papers, isn't it?

Comment: You can search on papers and it will provide links to them & content where available.

Comment: Does it provide "free access to thousands of paid articles"?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - It does __not__ provide _gratis_ access to papers that you should pay for it does provide _unfettered_ access to numerous paid sources, but you need to pay for, _or otherwise obtain_, the access.

Answer (score 0):

[DeepDyve](https://www.deepdyve.com/) can be considered a kind of "Spotify for papers". Their website claims:

> Enjoy unlimited access and personalized recommendations from over 12 million articles from more than 10,000 peer-reviewed journals.
>
> All for just $40/month

They offer a 14-days free trial so you can test the features. However, as far as I understand papers cannot be downloaded (they can be printed as raster images).

Comment: The linked page makes it look like an online service. OP asked for *desktop software* – so does this fit? Talking about prices: $30/month if you subscribe for a full year ;)

Comment: There is no desktop software that provides legal "access to thousand of papers". If it existed, you would need Internet access anyway.

Comment: Agreed – but I'm not the OP :)

Comment: Amongst these 12 millions, how many are open access?

Comment: I don't know, you can have a look if you want: https://www.deepdyve.com/browse/journals?page=all

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking only for a desktop app when you will have to be connected to the internet anyway to look at the articles?

Why not go with something online? [The US NIH PMC library](http://goo.gl/pm6eGr) has 3.9 million articles for free and the search is fairly good. If NIH only has the abstract, many articles have links to the full version for free.

Then you can use zotero.com to organize the studies and produce a bibliography. Zotero has a Firefox plugin to "catch" a study on a webpage for many different websites so you can make your personal library of studies.

Comment: Does it provide "free access to thousands of paid articles"?